# Are the versions of the two packages equivalent？

Tags: python, pytorch

Caution:These two python projects are based on conda environment.
When I tried to search for its packages,it shows two different  situations:

```
virtualenv1.torch           2.1.0+cu118(in pip list,and there are not pytorch)
virtualenv2.pytorch        2.0.1     py3.8_cuda11.7_cudnn8_0    pytorch (in conda list not pip list,in pip list,it shows torch    2.0.1
```

but it does not added +cu117)
So are these two versions equivalent?

when I tried to torch_cuda_is.available() ,they all show True.
I am expected to run a model,but I'm not sure virtualenv2 can do it .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.